# How to from query escaping comma and other special character in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a function which returns the comma separate values, but when I use

```
COALESCE(@Jiraids + ', ', '')
```

I get an error.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getCommonJiraIds](
    @selct varchar(100),
    @whereClause varchar(100),
    @id varchar(100),
    @TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID varchar(20) ) 
RETURNS varchar(max)   
AS
BEGIN        
     DECLARE @Jiraids VARCHAR(8000)      
     DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

     SET @whereClause = 'dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> '' AND  dbo.SNSTestResults.'+@whereClause+ ''+ QUOTENAME(@id,'''') + 'AND dbo.SNSTestResults.Test_result_info_ID_FK LIKE '+QUOTENAME(@TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID,'''')

     SET @sql = 'Select @Jiraids = COALESCE(@Jiraids + '', '', '') + case when (@selct LIKE Jira_ID_Maped) then Jira_ID_Maped else Jira_ID end

     FROM dbo.TestCaseList INNER JOIN dbo.SNSTestResults ON dbo.TestCaseList.TestCaseListID = dbo.SNSTestResults.TestCaseListID_FK'

     set @sql = @sql + @WhereClause

     EXEC @sql

    RETURN ( select @Jiraids);
END
```

When I execute the above function I got this error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetDailyCrJiraTable, Line 159
>   The name 'Select @Jiraids =COALESCE(@Jiraids + ', ', ') + case when (@selct LIKE Jira_ID_Maped) then Jira_ID_Maped else Jira_ID end FROM dbo.TestCaseList INNER JOIN dbo.SNSTestResults ON dbo.TestCaseList.TestCaseListID = dbo.SNSTestResults.TestCaseListID_FKdbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> ' AND   dbo.SNSTestResults.Jira_ID_Maped'UIBUG-4533'AND dbo.SNSTestResu' is not a valid identifier.

Somebody please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Already see several problems in your variables. Syntax is missing (such as the WHERE clause itself).z

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more `'`  to your `COALESCE` function as below

```
Select @Jiraids = COALESCE(@Jiraids + '', '', '''')
```

and as I said in comment you have to change this `dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> ''` 
to `dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> '''' AND`

Comment: the changes is still throwing the error ...Is where clause is correct in my query?

Comment: @vinay of course it's wrong try to change this `dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> ''` to `dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID` <> '''' AND

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @whereClause = 'dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> '''' AND  dbo.SNSTestResults.'+@whereClause+ ''+ QUOTENAME(@id,'''') + 'AND dbo.SNSTestResults.Test_result_info_ID_FK LIKE '+QUOTENAME(@TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID,'''')
```

you need more ' after dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID  <>

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getCommonJiraIds](
    @selct varchar(100),
    @whereClause varchar(100),
    @id varchar(100),
    @TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID varchar(20) ) 
  -- your four inputs
RETURNS varchar(max)   
AS
BEGIN        
     DECLARE @Jiraids VARCHAR(8000)      
     DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
     SET @whereClause = 'dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> ''
      AND  dbo.SNSTestResults.'+@whereClause+ ''+ QUOTENAME(@id,'''') 
      + 'AND dbo.SNSTestResults.Test_result_info_ID_FK LIKE '+QUOTENAME(@TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID,'''')
```

- you do not know it yet, but your Query does not actually have a WHERE clause written in.
- I hope you are not actually expecting the programmer to write extra
  code in your function everytime it is used.

  `SET @sql = 'Select @Jiraids = COALESCE(@Jiraids + '', '', '') + case when     (@selct LIKE Jira_ID_Maped) then Jira_ID_Maped else Jira_ID end
                   FROM dbo.TestCaseList INNER JOIN dbo.SNSTestResults ON     dbo.TestCaseList.TestCaseListID = dbo.SNSTestResults.TestCaseListID_FK`
- Your @selct has not been correctly identified. SQL SERVER cannot know
  at compile time that it is a @variable.
- Also, are you sure your function will only return one row? In some cases, being explicit about the expected occurrence (should someone actually use a '%' in their PREDICATE) can prevent a future breakdown in the code.

  ```
   set @sql = @sql + @WhereClause
   EXEC @sql
  ```

Thankfully, SO exists to help people out. :D
A correct version could be like the following:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getCommonJiraIds](
    @selct varchar(100),
    @whereClause varchar(100),
    @id varchar(100),
    @TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID varchar(20) ) 
    -- your four inputs
RETURNS varchar(max)   
AS
BEGIN        
     DECLARE @Jiraids VARCHAR(8000)      
     DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
     SET @sql = '
     Select @Jiraids = TOP 1 COALESCE(@Jiraids + '', '', '') + CASE WHEN (' + @selct + ' = Jira_ID_Maped) 
                                                        THEN Jira_ID_Maped 
                                                     ELSE Jira_ID END
     FROM   dbo.TestCaseList
     INNER  JOIN dbo.SNSTestResults ON dbo.TestCaseList.TestCaseListID = dbo.SNSTestResults.TestCaseListID_FK'
     SET @whereClause = 'WHERE dbo.SNSTestResults.JIRA_ID <> ''
                          AND  dbo.SNSTestResults.'+@whereClause+ ''+ QUOTENAME(@id,'''') 
                       + 'AND  dbo.SNSTestResults.Test_result_info_ID_FK LIKE '+QUOTENAME(@TEST_RESULT_INFO_ID, '')
     set @sql = @sql + @WhereClause
     EXEC @sql
    RETURN ( select @Jiraids);
END
```